# How to convert date time from one to another timezone with moment.js

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

i want to convert a datetime from given time zone(i have timezone offset for that),to local(browser's) time with the use of moment.js.

here is my code,

```
var date = "08/31/2017 02:45:00";
var timezone = '-330';
var d = moment.utc(date).utcOffset(timezone);
console.log(d.local().format());
```

now i want to convert this values to browser's timezone using moment.js

Comment: What is your issue? I think that [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/) does what you are looking for.

Comment: @VincenzoC i am not getting the exact UTC time from my date there is somethin wrong in calculating the UTC time

Answer (score 0):

```
d.local().format()
```

give you the date time converted to the browser time zone.
Check the [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5ywj7pbb/)